# Excel-VBA: Modify Application Without Using Password.

Tags: excel, password-protection, vba

I have developed an application using Excel-VBA and applied password protection to it to prevent modification. Now, I have forgotten the password and I want to update my application. Is there any way to modify the application without using the password?

Comment: Gray thanks for quick response.. In the above question password is known to user. And I have forgot the password.

Comment: Is that really your application? :P

Answer (score 0):

> My interpretation of this discussion
>   is that it is OK to provide a link to
>   password cracking software for
>   worksheet passwords, but not for
>   passwords protecting VBA code.
>
> To unprotect worksheets, I like the
>   code posted by Microsoft Excel MVP
>   Nico Sterk at
>   http://members.chello.nl/n.sterk/ExcelPages/Files/excel_files.htm
>   The BreakPassword macro in the
>   downloaded workbook will identify a
>   substitute password in about a minute.
>   It requires Excel 2000 and later. Here
>   is how to use it: 1) Click on any cell
>   in the worksheet that you want to
>   unprotect 2) ALT + F8 to open the
>   macro selector 3) Choose the
>   PasswordBreaker macro (from Nico
>   Sterk's workbook), then click the
>   "Run" button
>
> With Excel 97 and 2000, there is an
>   amazing loophole discovered by
>   MalicUK--just reset the password to an
>   empty string using VBA:

```
Sub UnprotectActiveSheet() 
 Dim ws As Worksheet 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet 
 ws.Protect "", , , , True 
 ws.Range("A1").Copy 
 ws.Range("A1") End 
Sub
```

-Anonymous

Comment: Mohamed I am getting "Pagina niet gevonden - (Error 404) " error when I clicked on provided link...